# What happens when a C++ implementation throws an exception to C code

Tags: c++, c, exception

So we have a public C header file (shooting for everything to be C callable)

```
 //foo.h
 #ifndef FOO_H
 #define FOO_H
 extern "C"
 {
   struct Foo;
   typdef FooHandle Foo*;

   FooHandle Foo_init();

   int Foo_bar(FooHandle handle);
 }
 #endif
```

And then the C++ header file:

```
 //foo.hpp
 #ifndef FOO_HPP
 #define FOO_HPP

 namespace my_foo
 {
   class Foo
   {
   public:
     int bar();
   };
 }
```

And than a source file:

```
 //foo.cpp
 #include "foo.h"
 #include "foo.hpp"
 #include <exception>

 void my_foo::Foo:bar() {throw std::exception();}

 FooHandle Foo_init() { return reinterpret_cast<FooHandle>(new my_foo::Foo());}
 int Foo_bar(FooHandle handle){
    my_foo::Foo& foo = *reinterpret_cast<my_foo::Foo*>(handle);
    foo.bar();
 }
```

What happens when I call Foo_bar from a pure C context (since C++ exceptions are not allowed) on various platforms? I know the behavior is probably "undefined", but I'm interested in what happens on various platforms.

Comment: Yes it is undefined. I don't quite see why it would be interesting to collect data of how different platforms implement a particular form of undefined behavior. Most likely: either the program will crash & burn or nothing at all will happen. Why don't you run the program and see for yourself?

Comment: @Lundin I'm trying to build an argument against using exceptions in this context...This was more of a "if anyone knows that'd be great" but I don't think any of us have the time to build this on a bunch of different systems and see what happens.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I don't think anyone knows how different UBs manifest on different systems, as this is not standarized. I don't think it is even possible to know. There is nothing sure there, so no-one can surely predict anything. Even if something happens in 99% cases, it might change on a whim.

Comment: If your C code needs to call into C++ code that utilizes exceptions, then you need a glue layer in between that will catch/mask/ignore/resolve any exceptions that actually do occur before returning something usable back to the C code. It may still be "undefined behavior" from a standards viewpoint, but at least it will then be "predictable" "reasonably behaved" "undefined behavior"

Comment: @twalberg I think that's what I'm going to say...with a combination of "there is no guarantee that the code will ever behave in any way consistently".

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++ code this way?

Comment: I think the normal way to mix these is like so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fb9e6c641b89b06 (Note the CPP class can't easily be in a namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Win32 C++ exceptions are implemented on top of SEH (structured exception handling). The exceptions propagate through C code and crash it unless C code catches them by SEH mechanism.

Comment: Actually, it depends on which exception handling model you select. Microsoft documents them here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx